# ¿Por qué pyrogram no funciona en Google colab?

Tags: python, jupyter, google-colab, ipython, asyncio

Estoy tratando de hacer un bot de telegram en Google colab con pyrogram pero, con tan solo poner lo básico que aparece en la página oficial de pyrogram, me da un error de que ya está corriendo o algo así.

Código:

```py
from pyrogram import Client, filters

app = Client("bot", api_hash=(mi API hash), api_id = (mi API id), bot_token=(mi bot token))

@app.on_message(filters.private)
async def hello(client, message):
    await message.reply("Hello from Pyrogram!")


app.run()
```

y el error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/run.py:84: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Start.start' was never awaited
  self.start()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-16a8a0b9e2f3> in <cell line: 9>()
      7     await message.reply("Hello from Pyrogram!")
      8 
----> 9 app.run()

2 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py in _check_running(self)
    582     def _check_running(self):
    583         if self.is_running():
--> 584             raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
    585         if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
    586             raise RuntimeError(

RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionar eso?

Comment: Prueba a reiniciarlo o algo así. Cómo vamos a poder ayudarte si lo único que nos dices es absolutamente nada técnico. 0 detalles! No somos adivinos. Usa el enlace [edit] y añade absolutamente toda la información necesaria para poder saber qué está pasando... log de errores, dependencias...

Comment: Obviamente no voy a poner el API hash el API id o el bot token XD

Comment: Sip, como es una pagina muy publica no deberias poner información sencible y reemplazarla por cualquier cosa. Nota: Si quieres responderle al usuario debes llamarlo @Benito-B

Comment: OK gracias @DABL03

Comment: @DABL03 El autor de una pregunta (o una respuesta) recibe notificaciones con los comentarios dejados en la misma sin necesidad de notificarlo si no recuerdo mal. A otros usuarios si debes citarlos para que sean notificados.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que colab usa Jupyter y el kernel de ipython se ejecuta en si mismo en un *event loop*. Pyrogram también hace uso de `asyncio`, el problema es que ésta [no permite la creación de ciclos de eventos anidados](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/66435).

De hecho se puede replicar el error con simplemente:

```
import asyncio

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(1))
```

La solución más común es usar [nest-async](https://pypi.org/project/nest-asyncio/), instalalo en el notebook con:

```
%pip install nest_asyncio
```

y luego antes de todo:

```
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()
```

Por ejemplo, ahora esto si funciona:

```
%pip install nest_asyncio
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()


async def hello_coroutine():
    print("¡Hola Mundo!")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(hello_coroutine())
```

No he probado en especifico con pyrogram, pero debería corregir el problema y permitir que pyrogram ejecute su event loop anidado sobre el que ya usa ipython:

```
%pip install nest_asyncio
%pip install pyrogram

from pyrogram import Client, filters
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

app = Client("bot", api_hash=(""), api_id = (""), bot_token=(""))

@app.on_message(filters.private)
async def hello(client, message):
    await message.reply("Hello from Pyrogram!")


app.run()
```

Comment: ```txt
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/run.py:84: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Start.start' was never awaited
  self.start()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```
sigue con ese Warning como quitarlo ?
pero aun asi el bot no responde al escribirle por telegram